# Does Google Ads receive signals from conversions sent via GA4?

Tags: google-bigquery, ads, google-analytics-4

The "purchase" conversion in GA4 is captured through measurement protocol (as it is known, such a conversion will not contain parameters such as geolocation, device, etc. - I have checked in BigQuery, and indeed, these parameters are not present; moreover, they cannot be passed according to Google's documentation, as they are collected automatically).

According to Google's recommendations, I transmit the ga_session_id value (via measurement protocol when sending "purchase"). As a result, my conversion has the correct source/channel (only conversions with a Google Ads source are visible in Google Ads).

Certainly, in all automatic events (session_start, first_visit, etc.), client parameters are collected based on the ga_session_id, such as geolocation, device, and more.

My final question: does Google Ads have access to all client parameters that it can discover by looking at other events based on the ga_session_id, or does Google Ads simply rely on the parameters of the specific "purchase" event, which lacks these parameters?

I tried sending "purchase" events automatically, and then I sent additional data via measurement protocol with a timestamp of the automatic event, hoping that the automatically collected data and my data would somehow merge, but it doesn't happen - the data sent with an existing timestamp_micros is not accepted in Google Analytics.

Comment: I received an answer on the Google platform but I'm not sure of its authenticity... https://support.google.com/google-ads/thread/236011282/does-google-ads-recognize-signals-from-conversions-sent-from-ga4?hl=en&sjid=3708271068474912848-EU